# Request a lua table size in c before iterating it

Tags: c, lua

This should be simple, and it probably is, but in my C code, I want to know the size of a table before I start iterating trough it. I need to preallocate some memory to store values in that come from that table.

I get this table as a parameter in a lua c function.

```
static int lua_FloatArray(lua_State *L)
{
 int n = lua_gettop(L);
 if (n != 1 || lua_gettype(L, 1) != LUA_TTABLE)
 {
  luaL_error(L, "FloatArray expects first parameter to be a table");
  return 0;
 }
 int tablesize = ????;
 float *a = (float*)lua_newuserdata(L, tablesize * sizeof(float));
 lua_pushnil(L);
 int x = 0;
 while (lua_next(L, index) != 0)
 {
  a[x++] = (float)lua_tonumber(L, -1);
  lua_pop(L, 1); // Remove value, but keep key for next iteration
 }
 return 1;
}
```

tablesize? how to get tablesize?

Comment: If you work with array table, use `lua_rawgeti` when iterating, it is much faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such API function. You need to count the items yourself.
On the other hand, you seem to be filling an array in C and I guess you have a Lua table like say `{10,20,30}`and you assume that you'll get the items in the order I've listed. This is *not so* with `lua_next`. See the second paragraph in http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-next .

Comment: That's not correct, the lua_objlen function returns the table size.

Comment: @scippie, not it doesn't. Try it on `{x=1}`.

Comment: I see. You are right. But I am using pure array tables and it works with them. Why the difference?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are working with arrays - tables with integer keys, without *holes* (some keys being **nil**) - you can use the [`lua_objlen`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_objlen) method. Quoting from the manual:

> Returns the "length" of the value at the given acceptable index: for strings, this is the string length; for tables, this is the result of the length operator ('#');

Comment: As of Lua 5.2 `lua_objlen` has been renamed to `lua_rawlen`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether this is actually good programming practice, but I often use 2d arrays / tables in the form of a structure

with a field for a ptr to your arrays (or pointer to array of pointers) and a field for number of columns and number of rows.

Comment: I think this isn't good unless you connect a garbage collect routine to the table that deletes the c ptr's.